# Absolute position div not filling the container div css

Tags: html, css

I have a `absolute positioned` div inside a container div. The background color of the absolute positioned div does not fill the container div. The height of the container div is dynamic according to the content. How to make the background color of the positioned div to fill it's container div?

Html:

```
<div class="container">
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />

<div class="showbg">
test
</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.container{ background-color:#CCCCCC;  width:300px;}
.showbg{ background-color:#FFFFFF; position:absolute; width:300px; margin-top:-65px; opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);}
```

Comment: make `.container` `position:relative` & remove unnecessary margins

Comment: what are you trying to do ? rgba() color on .container could do it. a one rgba() color in a background-image as linear-gradient hover an image, as well in background would do it too. even a hudge inset box-shadow with, afain, an rgba() color would work too. these options avoid to use an extra container. extra container could be produced via pseudo-element.

Answer (score 7):

```
.container {position: relative;}
.showbg {position:absolute; top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
.container{position:relative;}
.showbg{height:100%;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2CLtr/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit style for absolute div for following

```
.showbg
{
    top:0;
    bottom:0
}
```

for the absolute div with other style.

Answer (score 0):

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/pvr2Y/

```
.container {
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
}
.showbg {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
```